# Is all the kdb code written in the command prompt?

Tags: kdb

I want to learn kdb and I wanted to ask whether I have installed it correctly and whether all the code is inputted in the command prompt? I wrote til 11 and it gave me 1 through 10 so I believe ive done it correctly.

Comment: Would you be able to clarify this? For instance what version have you installed (4.0 is most recent)? Is it 32 or 64 bit, or on-demand (this will dictate whether a licence file is required)? Are you seeing any issues or errors at startup (If banner displays followed by a q prompt you should be ok)?

Comment: @SeanHehir Its the 32 bit one I installed for free on their website for windows. This pops up on startup: 
Welcome to kdb+ 32bit edition
For support please see http://groups.google.com/d/forum/personal-kdbplus
Tutorials can be found at http://code.kx.com  so I believe its correct. I have been making functions and things and its all been going well. How can I tell if a License is required? if its all good and working so far I assume it should be fine?

Comment: Part of the purpose of Stack Overflow is to help people in a similar situation find an answer to their problem in future. The more specific you can be in your question the more helpful it will be to other users who want to ask something similar in future (hence why specifying version, etc. would be encouraged for a question like this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have installed it correctly, you can check you've followed the steps correctly here:
https://code.kx.com/q/learn/install/

You also will want to make sure your `$QHOME` environment variable is set and pointing to the install directory as well as being present in your `$PATH` environment variable, e.g. in `.bashrc` on Linux:

`export QHOME=<path-to-directory>/q` and

`export PATH="<path-to-directory>/q/<version>/:$PATH"`.

Code can also be loaded in from a text file with a `.q` extension, e.g. from the command line:

`$ q script.q`

or when in a q session,

1. `q) \l script.q` ,
2. `q) system["l script.q"]`

The second provides more flexibility as it will work inside function calls.

See more about writing q scripts here:
https://kx.com/blog/kdb-q-insights-scripting-with-q/

There are also some IDE's available which you can read more about here:
https://code.kx.com/q/learn/tour/ide/

Comment: I didn't really follow these steps. I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozY1j2wPpkQ